# Web resources Development/debugging environment in VS 2015/2017

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, dynamics-crm-2016

I am looking how to organize the development/debugging environment of the D 365 CRM 2016 plugins/web resources to be integrated within Visual Studio 2015/2017 interactively.
And also the same for older versions of MS CRM again in VS 2015 and 2017.

I have just found this debugging way that sounds great but how can this be achieved with VS 2015/2017 and MS CRM Dynamics 2016:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devkeydet/2013/06/19/eureka-f5-debugging-of-crm-javascript-web-resources/

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you write tests for your code. This is likely to reduce the need to debug almost altogether. A popular resource to help you with your tests is [FakeXrmEasy](https://dynamicsvalue.com/get-started/overview).

For debugging web resources, there are many options. Here are two quick ways:

- Use a chrome browser and [Fiddler's auto response tool](http://develop1.net/public/post/Fiddler2-The-tool-that-gives-you-Superpowers-Part-1.aspx)
- Use [VS Code's Chrome debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code)

Comment: I agree with you - the tests are necessary supplements wherever and whenever possible to use them. But by MS CRM applications development and maintenance processes very often is needed to debug directly Web Resources scripts and the above described scenario is very useful and convenient - directly to modify source code(with some trace info e. g.) and update/publish it to some customized MS CRM instance while debugging in VS.